# Terrain correction in SAR image

Tags: gdal, dem, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, sar

I am new to the gdal utility. Using DEM data of the Moon, I am trying to perform terrain correction on SAR images. I have a DEM file and SAR data into tif file format. Both DEM and tif file are in Polarsterographic format. Can anyone suggest me how I can proceed the terrain correction using gdal.